# How to change ranking algorithm in mysql to match words in a row rather than term frequency?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am using full text search index to filter the records. Query looks like below:

SELECT name, MATCH (name) AGAINST ('TJ CNC 1 ADSP' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
FROM templates WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('TJ CNC 1 ADSP' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
order by 2 desc

This search is giving results based on term frequency in all rows(in `name` column). But the row which is having `name` exactly as `TJ CNC 1 ADSP` is being pushed to the last of the result set because not many records has keywords like TJ or CNC or 1.
Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

So how to get the search results in order based on their word presence in the name column instead of term frequency in all rows of the table?

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like problem is with ngram_token_size variable.

I have changed this value of this variable to 1 and converted search term `TJ CNC 1 ADSP` to `+TJ +CNC +1 +ADSP`(+ means that term should exist in the column).

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html